# Analog CMOS Design

Tags: analog, cmos, frequency-response

I have been studying CMOS design from Baker's book. In the amplifiers chapter he places a "big" resistor between the input gate and output drain of CS derived amplifier stages. What is its purpose? Is it used to push the zero to a much higher frequency?

This is a snip from the book:

[image]

Another instance:

[image]

Comment: Without that resistor, what would be the **DC voltage** at the gate of the transistor? Would that DC voltage be well defined or would it "depend on circumstances (like how much charge is on the gate)? Note that to **bias** a MOSFET at a certain current, there needs to be a well defined **DC voltage** at the gate.

Comment: The biasing is handled by the "Vbias" nets. They are part of a bigger Beta-Multiplier not shown here.

Comment: *The biasing is handled by the "Vbias" nets.* What then happens when the "Big" resistor isn't present and somehow the Vgs of the MOSFET is 0 V so the MOSFET is off, no current flows. Would it still be biased?

Answer (score 2):

"Big" values for those components is intended to indicate that they only affect the DC characteristics of the circuit, and are irrelevant with respect to the signal.

The big capacitor decouples the DC from the preceding circuit, and the big resistor applies negative feedback for the Q point, such that the transistor whose gate it is connected to sits roughly at its own threshold voltage.

Comment: I did some searching. As far as I understand, this "Big" resistor acts to damp high frequency small signal drain currents flowing through Cgd and Cgs. This serves the purpose of keeping the DC Gate voltage relatively constant during high frequency operation.

Comment: No one actually puts such resistors on-chip. The author means that the resistor is only used for dc operating point. This technique is used for ac small signal simulations. The big resistor can also be replaced by an infinite inductor. Baker explains this with slightly more details in his online lectures at cmosedu.com

Comment: So, instead of putting that big resistor in there can I bias the mosfet with other Vbias connections? Would it serve the same purpose for simulation?